# What do I need to include to call NtQueryAttributesFile?

Tags: windows, winapi

The developement environment that is necessary for using the windows native APIs confuses me greatly. I have gotten the WDK and included NtDll.lib. NtCreateFile works fine but when calling NtQueryAttributesFile, I get identifier undefined errors. What file am I missing?

My project already includes Windows.h, WinNt.h, fileapi.h.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/devnotes/ntqueryattributesfile) tells you:

> This function has no associated header file.

If you want to use this function you have to declare it yourself. The documentation tells you which signature and return value it has.

Comment: I am sory but i am not very familiar with this sort of thing. Does that mean that I have to write my own? I am trying to hook it with easyhook. That is pretty easy with regular functions. I have written a hook function that adds the functionality I need. At the end of it, I need to call the original function with the modified parameters. Any idea how I should declare it for it to still work with easyhook? Also the FILE_BASIC_INFORMATION struct is undefined as well.

Comment: *Does that mean that I have to write my own?* - this mean that you need *declare* it by self. compiler need only function declaration. implementation (for linker) already exist inside *ntdll.lib*

Comment: Thanks, i still need a bit of help however. I added this code to the top of my file but i still get a linker error. Did i do it correctly? 

`typedef struct _FILE_BASIC_INFORMATION {
 LARGE_INTEGER           CreationTime;
 LARGE_INTEGER           LastAccessTime;
 LARGE_INTEGER           LastWriteTime;
 LARGE_INTEGER           ChangeTime;
 ULONG                   FileAttributes;

} FILE_BASIC_INFORMATION, * PFILE_BASIC_INFORMATION;

NTSTATUS WINAPI NtQueryAttributesFile(_In_ POBJECT_ATTRIBUTES ObjectAttributes, _Out_ PFILE_BASIC_INFORMATION FileInformation);`

Comment: @enzeinzen did you add `Ntdll.lib` to your project? You can also use a `#pragma comment(lib, "ntdll.lib")` statement in your code, if your compiler supports that. Or, you can do what the documentation says: "*You can also **use the LoadLibrary() and GetProcAddress() functions** to dynamically link to Ntdll.dll.*"

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes it's in the project. Otherwise NtCreateFile wouldn't work and it does.

Comment: @enzeinzen - *Did i do it correctly?* - if you use *c* - yes, if *c++* - you need add *extern "C"* before function declaration (or do this inside more wide *extern "C" { }* block. also need add *__declscpec(dllimport)* or *NTSYSCALLAPI* or something similar

Comment: Thank you. it seems to work. This was the missing link in my ntdll wrapper that makes applications portable.